# Using Cups Reverse Orientation on a Postscript file

Tags: orientation, reverse, postscript, cups

When using the lp -o orientation-requested=6  in CUPS to print a postscript file, the first page is reversed 180 degrees and then the next page is back to 0 orientation.  Third page has the 180 degree rotation and fourth page back to 0 and so on.   I need  each page in the file to be reversed 180 degrees.  Any suggestions on what to try would be most appreciated.

Comment: Any other options you are using?

Comment: The situation you describe happens when you have `-o  sides=two-sided-short-edge`,  `-o orientation-requested=6 ` applies for ALL pages.

Answer (score 0):

If your PostScript file does not conform strictly to the PostScript DSC (document structuring convention), and the file is being sent to a PostScript printer, then whatever extras that CUPS may add to the pages may be getting overridden by ill-behaved per-page stuff in your document.  Unfortunately there's no particularly good fix for overcoming arbitrary ill-behaved PostScript code.  (The rotate-every-other-page or rotate-every-page-an-extra-180 behavior supports this via.

If it's your own application that's generating the PostScript file, you might benefit from comparing what you pipe into the spooler against what CUPS actually sends to the printer (you could capture it with netcat).